# React-Router clean urls with browserHistory and Anchor Tags

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

When using the default browserHistory for getting clean URLs I've had to use `<base href='\'>` to enable a) Refreshing browser and b) Provide static URLs

This however breaks using anchor tags: 
`<a href="#sectionId">Section</a>`

I also receive a warning for `Automatically setting basename using <base href> is deprecated..`

What is the best solution that supports both Clean URLs and Anchor Tags ?

Comment: Direct static URLs don't work. Like http://localhost:3000/user/1

Comment: Yes. Express, Webpack, NodeJS.

Comment: I had my reference to the bundle.js with a relative path that was breaking it initially and that fixed it. 
I use Auth0 and without the <base href=>, the callback URL breaks.

Comment: That probably is an Auth0 problem. I'll take it up with a different question. Will close this.